# How to properly create JQuery inArray if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am generating a list of random numbers. Each random number is added to an array, but I want to check that the same number isnt entered twice. I am having a lot of trouble trying to get the if statement to work with this and am not sure what I have done wrong.

I have created:

```
//INITIALISE VARS, ARRAYS
var uniquearr = [];
i = 0;

while (i < 30){

    var min = 0;
    var max = 29;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

    //SEARCH UNIQUE ARRAY FOR EXISTING
    if (jQuery.inArray(random, uniquearr) > -1){

        //ADD NUMBER TO UNIQUE ARRAY
        uniquearr.push(random);

        //*DO SOMETHING*

    } //END IF

    i++;

} //END WHILE
```

But the if statement never triggers. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe you should check `if (jQuery.inArray(random, uniquearr) < 0) { }`

Comment: he should also use correct code indenting, which should have made the error on the `END IF` line and `END WHILE` lines obvious.

Comment: Your condition is reversed, it will only add `random` if it already exists in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test whether the random number does **not** exist in the array; only then should it be added to the array.

Also another problem with the logic was, you were not adding the 30 unique numbers always as the `i` variable was incremented outside the `if` condition. Here you do not have to use a different loop variable since you can check whether the destination array is of desired size

```
//INITIALISE VARS, ARRAYS
var uniquearr = [], min = 0, max = 29;

//SEARCH UNIQUE ARRAY FOR EXISTING
while (uniquearr.length < 30){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    if (jQuery.inArray(random, uniquearr) == -1){
        uniquearr.push(random);
    }//END IF

}//END WHILE

console.log('uniquearr', uniquearr)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because your `if` statement always is `false`, your array is empty and as result `$.inArray`  always returns `-1`, you should check whether the returned value is -1 or not.

```
while (uniquearr.length < 30) { // uniquearr.length !== 30
    var min = 0,
        max = 29,
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    //SEARCH UNIQUE ARRAY FOR EXISTENCE
    if (jQuery.inArray(random, uniquearr) === -1) {
        //ADD NUMBER TO UNIQUE ARRAY
        uniquearr.push(random);
    } 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zzL7v/

Comment: best _code_ answer, but now please actually tell the OP what he did wrong, too.

Comment: if you check array length remove `i++;`, and also remove `;` at the end of the while and if blocks...